# Display sympy expressions in latex using pycharm/ipython

Tags: python, pycharm, latex, ipython, sympy

I am using **SymPy** and the scientific mode of **PyCharm** for symbolic calculations.

I would like to display latex code for printed out expressions in the integrated console. Using `qtconsole` this works fine, but i don't know how to make this work in the PyCharm console. I use `sympy.init_printing()` but the equations often look messy and are hard to read. **Sympy** also can convert symbolic expressions into strings containing the latex code.

so i would only need to know how to display the compiled latex expression, although it would be more convenient to make it work directly like in `qtconsole`.

I am using PyCharm 2019.3.1 with python 3.8.1 and the `ipython` console.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, this can be done using `display` from IPython:

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display

x, a, b = sym.symbols('x a b')
func = (a*x**b)/(a+b)

display(func)
```

This will print
[the compiled LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHWXx.png)
.